# Multicolumn Header aligned to left

Tags: tables, multicolumn, header

I'm doing some experiments with LaTeX and would like to know how to align the title of a multicolumn to the left.
This is the markup:

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{4.5cm}|p{10cm}|}
                    \hline
                    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Country List} \\
                    \hline
                    Afghanistan  & AF\\
                    Aland Islands&   AX\\
                    Albania &AL\\
                    Algeria    &DZ\\
                    American Samoa&   AS\\
                    Andorra& AD\\
                    Angola& AO\\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox} 
\end{table}

\section{Section title}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{Subsection title}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

And this is what I see:

[image: screenshot]

I'd like to place the Country List aligned to the left, like the rest of the table's contents. It's possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yes, very possible: use `\multicolumn{2}{l}{Country}`

Comment: Or `\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Country}` if you want to keep the tow vertical lines on the outside of the table.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend to not use `adjustbox` to make a table fit into the textwidth as it will lead to inconsistent font sizes. You could use `tabularx` instead. For your example, there is also not really a need for `p` type columns as the contents of the columns are already quite narrow and you don't need linebreaks inside of them. Why not simply go for two `l` type columns?

Comment: Thank you all, but `\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Country}` and `\multicolumn{2}{l}{Country}` seems that they don't work... I think I'll try tabularx ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Type

```
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Country List}
```

instead of

```
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Country List}
```

Comment: seems not working...

Comment: Sure about that? It works for me.

Comment: it works if I remove it from the adjust box...

Comment: Anyway, you shouldn't use `adjustbox` for table – it leads to inconsistent font sizes. There are may other ways to fit a table within margins.

Comment: Indeed, I removed it, and the title has aligned left! ;)